# why db.insertWithOnConflict return -1 here?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

In this activity, we can enter information of a school's test, and add it to others one.

#### Test.java :

```
package com.example.amirmasoudfallahi.testcorrector;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;

/**
 * Created by AmirMasoud Fallahi on 11/18/2017.
 */

public class Test {

  public static final String KEY_ID = "testID";
  public static final String KEY_NAME = "testName";
  public static final String KEY_SCHOOL_NAME = "schName";
  public static final String KEY_QUESTION_NUM = "quesNum";
  public static final String KEY_PARTICIPANT_NUM = "participantNum";
  public static final String KEY_QUALITY_MARK = "qualityMark";
  public static final String KEY_LESSON_NUM = "lessonNum";

  private int testID;
  private String testName;
  private String schName;
  private int quesNum;
  private int participantNum;
  private float qualityMark = 0;
  private int lessonNum;

  public int getLessonNum() {
    return lessonNum;
  }

  public void setLessonNum(int lessonNum) {
    this.lessonNum = lessonNum;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return testName;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.testName = name;
  }

  public String getSchName() {
    return schName;
  }

  public void setSchName(String schName) {
    this.schName = schName;
  }

  public int getQuesNum() {
    return quesNum;
  }

  public void setQuesNum(int quesNum) {
    this.quesNum = quesNum;
  }

  public int getParticipantNum() {
    return participantNum;
  }

  public void setParticipantNum(int participantNum) {
    this.participantNum = participantNum;
  }

  public float getQualityMark() {
    return qualityMark;
  }

  public void setQualityMark(float qualityMark) {
    this.qualityMark = qualityMark;
  }

  public int getId() {
    return testID;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.testID = id;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return testName;
  }

  public ContentValues getContentValuesForDb(){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Test.KEY_ID, testID);
    values.put(Test.KEY_NAME, testName);
    values.put(Test.KEY_SCHOOL_NAME, schName);
    values.put(Test.KEY_QUESTION_NUM, quesNum);
    values.put(Test.KEY_LESSON_NUM, lessonNum);
    values.put(Test.KEY_QUALITY_MARK, qualityMark);
    values.put(Test.KEY_PARTICIPANT_NUM, participantNum);
    return values;
  }

  public static Test cursorToTest(Cursor cursor){
    Test test = new Test();
    test.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
    test.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
    test.setQuesNum(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUESTION_NUM)));
    test.setParticipantNum(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_PARTICIPANT_NUM)));
    test.setSchName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCHOOL_NAME)));
    test.setQualityMark(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUALITY_MARK)));
    test.setLessonNum(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LESSON_NUM)));
    return test;
  }

}
```

#### TestDbHelper.java :

```
package com.example.amirmasoudfallahi.testcorrector;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by AmirMasoud Fallahi on 11/20/2017.
 */

public class TestDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static final String DB_NAME = "test-db";
  private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

  public static final String TABLE_TESTS = "tb_tests";
  private static final String CMD =
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '" + TABLE_TESTS + "' ('" +
      Test.KEY_ID + "' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE, '" +
      Test.KEY_NAME + "' TEXT, '" +
      Test.KEY_SCHOOL_NAME + "' TEXT, '" +
      Test.KEY_QUESTION_NUM + "' INTEGER, '" +
      Test.KEY_LESSON_NUM + "' INTEGER, '" +
      Test.KEY_QUALITY_MARK + "' REAL, '" +
      Test.KEY_PARTICIPANT_NUM + "' INTEGER " +
      ")";

  private static final String[] allColumns = {Test.KEY_ID, Test.KEY_NAME, Test.KEY_SCHOOL_NAME,
    Test.KEY_QUESTION_NUM, Test.KEY_PARTICIPANT_NUM, Test.KEY_QUALITY_MARK, Test.KEY_LESSON_NUM};


  public TestDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CMD);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TESTS);
    onCreate(db);
  }

  public void insetItem(Test test) {
//    if(getTests(Test.KEY_ID + " = " + test.getId()).isEmpty()) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    long insertId = db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_TESTS, null, test.getContentValuesForDb(), SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    if(insertId == -1) {
      Log.i("TestDbHelper", "data insertion failed. (item : " + test.toString() + ")");
    } else {
      Log.i("TestDbHelper", "data inserted with id : " + insertId);
    }
    if(db.isOpen()) db.close();
//    }
  }

  public List<Test> getTests(String selection){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    List<Test> testList = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TESTS, allColumns, selection, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
      do{
        Test test = Test.cursorToTest(cursor);
        testList.add(test);
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    if(db.isOpen()) db.close();
    return testList;
  }

}
```

#### DefineTestActivity.java :

```
package com.example.amirmasoudfallahi.testcorrector;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class DefineTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  TestDBHelper dbHelper;
  EditText inputTestName, inputSchName, inputPrtNum, inputQuesNum, inputLessNum;
  Button subTest;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_define_test);

    dbHelper = new TestDBHelper(this);

    inputTestName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_testNameIn);
    inputSchName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_schNameIn);
    inputPrtNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_prtcpntNumIn);
    inputQuesNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_testQuesNumIn);
    inputLessNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_lessNum);
    subTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_createTestSubmit);

    subTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setName(inputTestName.getText().toString().trim());
        test.setSchName(inputSchName.getText().toString().trim());
        test.setQuesNum(Integer.parseInt(inputQuesNum.getText().toString().trim()));
        test.setParticipantNum(Integer.parseInt(inputPrtNum.getText().toString().trim()));
        test.setLessonNum(Integer.parseInt(inputLessNum.getText().toString().trim()));

        dbHelper.insetItem(test);

        Intent intent = new Intent(DefineTestActivity.this, AnswerKeysActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("lessonNum", test.getLessonNum());
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

#### Activity Preview:

[[image: activity preview]]

in this case, I'm entering information of new Test to be added to Tests list.
when I press the button it should add a new Test to test's table in database.
as you see, in this line it should add it:

```
dbHelper.insetItem(test);
```

is insert function, in this line:

```
long insertId = db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_TESTS, null, test.getContentValuesForDb(), SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

it should add it and return a non -1 .
but it return -1, it shows our insertion did failed.

there is no errors. And I actually don't know why it get -1 and didn't insert the item in DB.

Can anyone solve this problem???

Comment: Use `insertOrThrow()`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have some appropriate constraint in your table, such as PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE.
When inserting, add a value to this constrained column via ContentValues. If inserting the new row would violate some constraint, the conflicting rows are first deleted and then the new row is inserted.
In your case, COLUMN_ID looks like a good candidate for PRIMARY KEY constraint. The second arg nullColumnHack with value COLUMN_ID in your code is not necessary, you can pass it as null.

Comment: first, I passed nullColumnHack as null, as you see in code. Second, I have set the "testID" as Primary Key. I did them before, but still it doesn't work..

Comment: Honestly speaking buddy, why don't you make use of ROOM library (Android's official library for database storage). You won't have to scratch your head over these silly database errors. I personally found out this as the most helpful manual: https://blog.mindorks.com/sqlite-made-easy-room-persistence-library-ecd1a5bb0a2c